# Creating a subset of a dataset by taking the mean values for each date in R

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, timeserieschart

Using Rstudio with tidyverse plugin, using ggplot2 to plot:

Say we have a dataset called SoccerTeam, this data set consists of variables: Location, Goals, YearPlayed, etc... and each data entry is assigned to a game, so the game was played at Location X, they scored Y Goals, It was played in year 19XX.

In the YearPlayed we have all the years the team has been active for, say years 1950 to 2020 and there is a whole season of data for each year.

Lets say that 2002 has 30 games, so there would be 30 data entries that have YearPlayed = 2002.

Our goal is to plot over time how many goals the team has scored. If we take into account every single game from each year and plot it over the 70 years of play, our graph would be very messy and hard to interpret. To tackle this issue, I would like to take the average goals for each year and plot that over time. How would i do this?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a general introduction to data wrangling in R, I recommend [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/).  That said, you need to group by the column YearsPlayed, and then compute the mean for each year.  Then, pipe it into the plot commands.  The `%>%` symbol send the left side's output into the right side.  So you can chain them together like this:

```
SoccerTeam %>% 
  group_by(YearPlayed) %>%
  summarize(Goals = mean(Goals)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=YearPlayed, y=Goals) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.